# Remapping between nodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to remap between nodes in launch file. Plz guide.im using Ros indigo version

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275982/remapping-between-nodes/) by [Lodha.sagar39](https://answers.ros.org/users/32638/lodha.sagar39/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-15**:
There is quite some [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) [available](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) and ROS Answers has some Q&As about it as well.

Can you explain what it is exactly that is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, remap is a feature to rename topics, node names and some special keys of ROS env. You can see in this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) what you can remap, like  a node name (__node), namespace (__ns), log file (__log), etc.

Example:
I've a node that publishes Twist messages in a topic called `turtlebot_vel`, but my robot listens to `cmd_vel`

You can remap using `rosrun` command, like this:

```
rosrun my_pkg my_node.py turtlebot_vel:=cmd_vel
```

Or inside a launch file ([ref](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)):

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node.py" name="my_node">
        <remap from="turtlebot_vel" to="cmd_vel"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0